# How to build/transform an object from a previous object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm trying to create an object in a certain structure from data that I have.
From:

```js
// example #1
const dataGender = {"male": 30, "female": 70}

// example #2
const dataFruits = {"apple": 10, "banana": 20, "strawberry": 200}
```

to:

```js
const resultGender = {
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 30, "label": { "en": "male"}
        },
        {
            "value": 70, "label": { "en": "female"}
        }
    ]
}

const resultFruits = {
    "data": [
        {
            "value": 30, "label": { "en": "apple"}
        },
        {
            "value": 20, "label": { "en": "banana"}
        },
        {
            "value": 200, "label": { "en": "strawberry"}
        }
    ]
}
```

In other words, a function that accepts `dataGender` and returns `resultGender`, and likewise for `dataFruits`.

As can be seen above, the structure is consistent, and the only changes are to the values under keys `"value"` and `"en"`.

I found `ramda`'s `objOf()` which brings me close:

```js
const R = require("ramda")

const buildObject = R.compose(
  R.objOf("data"),
  R.map(R.objOf("value"))
);
buildObject([30, 70]); // => {"data": [{"value": 30}, {"value": 70}]}
```

But I'm still missing how to build the textual part under `"en"`.

Comment: Is there a strong reason you want to use Ramda for this?  A vanilla implementation is pretty simple: `const transform = (o) => ({data: Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => ({value: v, label: {en: k}}))})`.  Don't get me wrong, I'm a Ramda founder, and a big fan, but don't know why you're trying to use it here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, thanks. Not a strong reason for ramda actually. It's just that the built-in `objOf()` seemed an inch away from my desired output. Your suggestion is super nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the object to pairs of `[key, value]`, and map them to a new object using `R.applySpec`. Use `R.nth` to take the key or value from the pair. Use `R.objOf` to nest the array under `data`.

```js
const { pipe, toPairs, map, applySpec, nth, objOf } = R

const fn = pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(applySpec({
    value: nth(1),
    label: {
      en: nth(0)
    }
  })),
  objOf('data')
)

// example #1
const dataGender = {"male": 30, "female": 70}

// example #2
const dataFruits = {"apple": 10, "banana": 20, "strawberry": 200}

console.log(fn(dataGender))
console.log(fn(dataFruits))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

The main behavior is taking an object, converting it pairs, and then applying a spec to each pair. We can extract this to a function (`mapSpec`), and then build are specific function with it:

```js
const { curry, map, toPairs, applySpec, pipe, nth, objOf } = R

const mapSpec = curry((spec, obj) => map(
  applySpec(spec),
  toPairs(obj)
))

const fn = pipe(
  mapSpec({
    value: nth(1),
    label: {
      en: nth(0)
    }
  }), 
  objOf('data')
)

// example #1
const dataGender = {"male": 30, "female": 70}

// example #2
const dataFruits = {"apple": 10, "banana": 20, "strawberry": 200}

console.log(fn(dataGender))
console.log(fn(dataFruits))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Whoa this is outstanding! Thank you!

Comment: So of course this works very well. But I'm trying to break it down so I could re-use this solution when I need to create other structures. The second expression in the pipe is `R.map()`. We know that `map()` take a function and applies it over data, so `applySpec({value: nth(1), label: { en: nth(0) }})` is the function being mapped. My question is how could be extract this function to be a more general standalone?

Comment: Here's my [REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.28.0#?const%20dataGender%20%3D%20%7B%22male%22%3A%2030%2C%20%22female%22%3A%2070%7D%0Aconst%20asPairs%20%3D%20toPairs%28dataGender%29%0A%0Aconst%20myLabels%20%3D%20map%28nth%280%29%2C%20asPairs%29%0Aconst%20myValues%20%3D%20map%28nth%281%29%2C%20asPairs%29%0A%0A%2F%2F%20make%20applySpec%20a%20standalone%20for%20this%20structure%0AapplySpec%28%7Bvalue%3A%20myValues%2C%20label%3A%20%7B%20en%3A%20myLabels%7D%7D%29)

Comment: I've added an example of a more generic function

Comment: Thanks! Your update is helpful but not exactly what I meant. Consider the following builder functions: **(1)** `const buildArr1 = R.pipe(R.toPairs, R.map(R.applySpec({value: R.nth(1), label: {en: R.nth(0)}})))`; **(2)** `const buildArr2 = R.pipe(R.toPairs, R.map(R.applySpec({count: R.nth(1), label: {en: R.nth(0)}})))`; 
**(3)** `const buildArr3 = R.pipe(R.toPairs, R.map(R.applySpec({value: R.nth(0), count: R.nth(1)})))`. We see that the part inside `applySpec()` slightly differs between the builders. So I wonder if it's possible to extract the inner structure and supply it as desired format.

Comment: Maybe it's worth a new post, but since we're at the context here I thought it's relevant...

Comment: That's hard to read. It's time for a new question.