# How to create a builder function that transforms key-value data, and is supplied with both the data and the structure/format of the output

Tags: javascript, function, ramda.js

*This is a follow-up question to: [How to build/transform an object from a previous object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71032048/6105259)*

Given data in a key-value format, I want to transform it into a new structure.

```js
// given data example #1
const dataAnimals = {"monkeys": 10, "alligators": 20}

// given data example #2
const dataColors = {"red": 100, "green": 4, "yellow": 17}
```

And the new structure of the *output* can be chosen from any prespecified format.
If we stick with `dataAnimals` as the input, there are three possible output formats:

*structure type 1*

```json
[
    {
        label: {
            en: "monkeys"
        },
        value: 10
    },
    {
        label: {
            en: "alligators"
        },
        value: 20
    }
]
```

*structure type 2*

```json
[
    {
        count: 10,
        label: {
            en: "monkeys"
        }
    },
    {
        count: 20,
        label: {
            en: "alligators"
        }
    }
]
```

*structure type 3*

```json
[
    {
        count: 10,
        value: "monkeys"
    },
    {
        count: 20,
        value: "alligators"
    }
]
```

I'm likely to have several more types of structures.

---

I wonder if there's a way to *supply* the chosen/desired structure (i.e., pass the structure to a builder function alongside the input data itself).

So far, using `ramda` I could only write 3 separate builder functions with the structure being hard-coded inside each:

```js
const buildArr1 = R.pipe(R.toPairs, R.map(R.applySpec({value: R.nth(1), label: {en: R.nth(0)}})))
const buildArr2 = R.pipe(R.toPairs, R.map(R.applySpec({count: R.nth(1), label: {en: R.nth(0)}})))
const buildArr3 = R.pipe(R.toPairs, R.map(R.applySpec({value: R.nth(0), count: R.nth(1)})))

buildArr1(dataAnimals)
buildArr2(dataAnimals)
buildArr3(dataAnimals)
```

The differences between `buildArr1()`, `buildArr2()`, and `buildArr3()` are subtle and only in terms of the structure inside `applySpec()`. So it got me thinking, whether it's possible to have just ***one*** function `buildArr()`, that takes as input both the data to transform and the format to be returned.

```js
// pseudo-code for desired code
buildArr(dataAnimals, structureType1)
// which will return
// [
//     {
//         label: {
//             en: "monkeys"
//         },
//         value: 10
//     },
//     {
//         label: {
//             en: "alligators"
//         },
//         value: 20
//     }
// ]


buildArr(dataAnimals, structureType2)

// [
//     {
//         count: 10,
//         label: {
//             en: "monkeys"
//         }
//     },
//     {
//         count: 20,
//         label: {
//             en: "alligators"
//         }
//     }
// ]
```

Is there any proper way to do something like that? I'm also not sure what should be the nature of `structureType1`/`structureType2` being passed. An object? Or rather a function that "knows to interact" with the input data?

Please note that while this question revolves around `ramda`, it seems (to me) to be broader than a specific library.

---

EDIT

---

User [@Scott Sauyet has nicely pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71032048/how-to-build-transform-an-object-from-a-previous-object#comment125578757_71032048) that writing the individual builders (i.e., `buildArr1()`, `buildArr2`, etc.) could be achieved with plain JS. This speaks to my point above, that this isn't necessarily a `ramda` question.

```js
const buildArr1PlainJS = (o) => ({data: Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => ({value: v, label: {en: k}}))})
const buildArr2PlainJS = (o) => ({data: Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => ({count: v, label: {en: k}}))})
const buildArr3PlainJS = (o) => ({data: Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => ({value: k, count: v}))})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this fairly easily by passing in a formatting function to a generic processor.  It might look something like this:

```js
// main function
const transform = (fn) => (o) => Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => fn (k, v))

// formatting functions
const format1 = transform ((k, v) => ({label: {en: k}, value: v}))
const format2 = transform ((k, v) => ({count: v, label: {en: k}}))
const format3 = transform ((k, v) => ({count: v, value: k}))

// input data
const inputs = {
  dataAnimals: {"monkeys": 10, "alligators": 20},
  dataColors: {"red": 100, "green": 4, "yellow": 17},
};

// demo
Object .entries (inputs) .forEach (([name, input]) => [format1, format2, format3] .forEach ((format, i) =>
  console .log (`${name}, format ${i + 1}:`, format (input))
))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Again, I don't see Ramda adding much value here, although we could of course do this  with Ramda's tools.  We might write:

```js
const transform = (fn) => (o) => map (unapply (fn)) (toPairs (o))
```

Or if you had a point-free fetish, even this:

```js
const transform = compose (flip (o) (toPairs), map, unapply)
```

But I don't think these -- especially the latter -- add anything useful.